# Castle Windsor registering component

Tags: castle-windsor

I am new to IoC and especially castle windsor.
Can someone explain to me the differences between part1 and part2? My understanding is part1 is where you register components and part2 is a factory where it creates object. I am not sure what component means in this context. I read some of the documentation http://docs.castleproject.org/ but cannot seem to find where it explains these 2 in detail.

```
container.Register
(
//part1
AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<AnotherClass>()
.BasedOn<ISomething>()
.WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
.WithService.Self(),
//part2
Component.For<ISomething>().ImplementedBy<Something>()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Result is the same: registering component(s) in the container.

The first approch allows to register multiple components matching a set of criteria. In your case you are registering all classes implementing `ISomenthing` contained in the assemby which contains `AnotherClass`, then using `With`... You are making your components resolvable through the `DefaultInterfaces` (read the wiki for details) or through the type itself.

The second approach is more straight forward... You are registering only one component which Will be resolvable by its `ISomenthing` interface only